# Ideals whose alebraic variety is a singleton

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, polynomials, differential-operators, grassmannians, prime-ideals

I do not work in algebra, so i apologize in advance if there are some unclear/wrong sentences. Let us consider the ring $\mathbb{C}[X_1,\ldots,X_q]$ of polynomials in $q$ variables. For an ideal $I$ of this ring we associate its variety
$$V(I) = \left\lbrace(x_1,\ldots,x_q)\in\mathbb{C}^q \quad\middle | \quad P(x_1,\ldots,x_q) = 0\quad\forall P\in I\right\rbrace.$$
I'm interested in the set
$$E = \left\lbrace I\text{  ideals of } \mathbb{C}[X_1,\ldots,X_q]\quad\middle |\quad V(I) = \lbrace(0,\ldots,0)\rbrace\right\rbrace$$
That is, the sets of ideals whose corresponding algebraic variety consists only in the origin point. One can define the multiplicity of an element ideal $I$ in $E$ as
$$mult(I) = \dim \mathbb{C}[X_1,\ldots,X_q]/I,$$
and for $p\geq 1$ the space
$$E_p = \left\lbrace I\in E\quad\middle |\quad mult(I) = p\right\rbrace.$$
Is there any known natural differentiable structure on the space $E_p$ ?

Following [this article](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1996-348-08/S0002-9947-96-01671-6/S0002-9947-96-01671-6.pdf), an ideal in $E_p$ can be described as a collection of $p$ differential conditions at the origin, who must satisfies some closeness condition (in order to be an ideal). Thus a natural topology would be the topology induced by the Grassmannian $Gr(p,V)$, where $V$ is the set of differential operators whose order do not exceed $p-1$.

Second question, can we prove that topologically,
$$\dim(E_p) = (p-1)(q-1)\quad ?$$
For instance if $q=1$ then $E_p$ consists in the only ideal $\langle X^p\rangle$ and thus $\dim(E_p) = 0$. For $q>1$, there is a one-to-one correspondence between $E_2$ and $\mathbb{S}^{q-1}$ given by the mapping
$$\theta\mapsto \left\lbrace\quad P \quad\middle|\quad P(0) = 0\quad\text{and}\quad \partial_\theta P(0) = 0   \right\rbrace,$$
it yields $\dim(E_2) = q-1$. On can also prove in a similar fashion that $\dim(E_3) = 2(q-1)$ but for $p>3$ it gets a bit messy.

Comment: Are you **sure** you wish to ask about real ideals $I$ whose only *real* point is the origin rather than those whose only *complex* (=geometric) point is the origin? For example, with the definition you wrote, the ideal $(X_1^2+X_2^2)$ in $\mathbb{R}[X_1,X_2]$ is in $E$, although it is not zero-dimensional in any way, and in particular $\operatorname{mult}(I)$ is infinite, which seems to go against the fact that you seem to want to know geometric things about zero-dimensional ideals. So I think your question needs fixing.

Comment: (contd.) So: either your questions are really geometrical in nature, in which case you should fix them (change $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{C}$ in the definition of $V(I)$ and maybe elsewhere as well; so then $E$ is the set of ideals having $(X_1,\ldots,X_q)$ as radical); or alternatively, if you really mean $\mathbb{R}$ then you should explain $\operatorname{mult}(I)$ better, and start by stating what you already know about ideals such that $V(I)$ has *no* real point.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, indeed it makes sense to replace $\mathbb{R}$ by $\mathbb{C}$, i edited my question. My question is indeed really geometrical in nature. I want to understand "how" $p$ points can be 'infinitely' close to each other. If a generic sequence of polynomial cancels on $p$ distinct points that collapse to a single point, what can I say about the limiting polynomial if it exists ? Well it has to lie in some $E_p$, so now the goal is to understand who is $E_p$. I figure it's been done already but I cannot find any reference.

Comment: In this case, a keyword which you should try searching for if you do not already know about it is “Hilbert scheme of zero-dimensional subschemes” (there is a book by Lothar Göttsche with this title) or “punctual Hilbert schemes” (there is a book by Anthony Iarrobino with this title). What you call $E_p$ is the “Hilbert scheme of $0$-dimensional subschemes of length $p$ supported at the origin” (or some analogous description). And unfortunately, it tends to be not at all smooth, nor even irreducible.

Comment: (In fact, if I remember correctly, of the the surprises about these objects is that, for $p$ large enough, there exist entire components of this Hilbert scheme which are not specializations of $p$ distinct points. I think this result is by Iarrobino, but I don't remember where I learned it.)

Comment: I don,t know anything about schemes but this indeed seems exactly to be the object that I need. What is the intuition behind "not beeing specializations of $p$ distincts points" ? Does it mean that one cannot find a sequence of distinct point such that the associated "ideal" converge to the limit ideal we are considering ?

I will try to find good references on this topic that explains things without too much algebraic geometry... From what I gather the case q=1,2 are well understood and are close to intuition, but not higher dimensional spaces.

Comment: I still don't need much about these spaces, only their dimension and maybe a smooth/stratified manifold structure would already be nice. My problem is very simple, I have a function that depends on p points, whose expression is singular when points collapses and I try to understand the singularity. There is I believe others path to solve my problem than by solving explicitly the singularity, but knowing that its hard is a very interesting property :)

Comment: “Not being specialization of $p$ distinct points” means what you guessed: a reference for this is [Iarrobino, “Reducibility of the families…” *Invent. Math* **15** (1972) 72–77](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01418644). It's essentially a dimension-count argument: the Hilbert space in question has a larger dimension than the space of $p$ distinct points, so it must contain other components. That even the dimension count isn't easy suggest that its exact value isn't known, but I'm not sure. Maybe try re-asking the question with the “right” terminology. \[contd.\]

Comment: \[contd.\] I suggest you try reading the beginning of Göttsche's book I mentioned in an earlier comment (especially §2.1) and Iarrobino's paper I just cited, and perhaps search for other papers citing them, and if they don't contain what you want, re-ask the question on MathOverflow with terms like “Hilbert scheme of $0$-dimensional subschemes” and the notation from the references in paper: this will likely draw more attention from people more knowledgeable than I am.

Comment: PS: Don't let the term “subscheme” frighten you: a subscheme of $\mathbb{A}^n_{\mathbb{C}}$ is just given by an ideal of $\mathbb{C}[t_1,\ldots,t_n]$, it is zero-dimensional iff the quotient is a finite-dimensional vector space, in which case the “length” refers to the dimension of the quotient. (But you probably inferred all this already.)

Comment: Thank you for yours answers it helps a lot ! I checked the literature and its really wonderful. From what I gathered I'm interested in fact in the "smoothable" component of the Hilbert scheme (i.e. specializations of $p$ distincts points) and it has an explicit construction as a blow up of the diagonal of $(\mathbb{R}^q)^p$ quotiented by the symmetric group action. I will keep reading papers and if I'm struggling or that I need some intuition I will ask the question again in better terms.